# Mysql - How to return more than 1 row for stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, subquery, procedure

Help i need help for a stored procedure that i'm trying to make.

I want the procedure to return all giftcards by a userame, that will be expired within 3 weeks (21) days.

I've tried everything from GROUP_CONCAT to Cursor but it keeps telling me

```
Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

Here is my stored procedure

```
CREATE DEFINER=`giftcard`@`%` PROCEDURE `CheckExpiryDate`(IN username 
VARCHAR(24))
BEGIN

Declare LoginID INT;
Declare UserID INT;

SET LoginID = (SELECT LoginID From Login WHERE `UserName` = username);
SET UserID = (SELECT UserID From User WHERE `User`.`LoginID` = LoginID);

SELECT * FROM Giftcard WHERE DATEDIFF(ExpiryDate, now()) <= 21 AND `Giftcard`.`UserID` = UserID;

END
```

I want something like this
http://tinypic.com/r/2u7t8q9/8
But just with a specific userid from a given username in the parameter.

Comment: Are you certain that your `LoginID` and `UserID` queries return only a single row?

Comment: see http://tinypic.com/r/2u7t8q9/8

Comment: @user3896882 I'd like to see if the error goes away if you wrapped both `LoginID` and `UserID` in a `max()` function, such as: `SET LoginID = (SELECT max(LoginID) from Login WHERE UserName = username);`. Your error is referencing a subquery, and both of your subqueries aren't "guaranteed" to return a single row, and that might be what the database is complaining about.

Comment: @Dan That wont work since every user have a different loginId see http://tinypic.com/r/dfin1f/8

Comment: this work though `CREATE DEFINER=`giftcard`@`%` PROCEDURE `CheckExpiryDate`(IN userid int(24))
BEGIN

SELECT * FROM Giftcard WHERE DATEDIFF(ExpiryDate, now()) <= 21 AND `Giftcard`.`UserID` = userid; 

END`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't fix the problem because you are trying to fix the SQL without understanding the data.

The trick to trying to fix a subquery returns more than one value is to find the actual values it would be returning and the determine how to get only one returned. It could be through an aggregate function, an additional where clause, or it could mean that you want all the records and thus can't use a subquery at all. Those are business rule choices and we can't help you with that.

The dateadiff part of your query above is not a subquery so I am confused as to why you think it is the problem.  If you put the select in just to show what the results would be if you were running other code that actually has a subquery, then you look at that data to determine what you want. If you want all of them, then you need to change the code with the subquery to use a join instead of a subquery.  If you only want one, you need to determine which where condition(s) or aggreagate function(s) would get you the record you want.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working now as i wanted

```
CREATE DEFINER=`giftcard`@`%` PROCEDURE `CheckExpiryDate`(IN un VARCHAR(24))
BEGIN

DECLARE lid INT;
DECLARE uid INT;
SET lid = (SELECT LoginID FROM Login WHERE UserName = un);
SET uid = (SELECT UserID FROM User WHERE LoginID = lid);

SELECT * FROM Giftcard WHERE DATEDIFF(ExpiryDate, now()) <= 21 AND `Giftcard`.`UserID` = uid; 

END
```

Comment: i think it got confused by calling the declarations and the parameter the same given name